# GIT: projeto com 2 versoes em diferentes clientes e ramo principal

Tags: git, github, versionamento, bitbucket

estou com uma duvida em relacao a organizacao do GIT.

Tenho 1 projeto que irá se dividir em 2 versoes para clientes distintos, gostaria de manter um ramo principal e que as alteracoes genericas fossem feito nesse ramo e replicado para as 2 versoes, porem cada versao tera suas alteracoes unicas tb.

O ideal seria fazer com fork ou com branches?

Comment: Eu diria que o ideal seria ter uma configuração que iria seguir o caminho A ou o caminho B, ter dois códigos fontes separados pode lhe dar muita dor de cabeça (experiência própria)

Comment: Mas ai cada melhoria generica eu vou ter que ficar replicando para N projetos, nao acho que seja inteligente isso.

O produto é o mesmo, so temos 2 versoes levemente diferentes para clientes especificos.

Comment: Dependendo do número de arquivos do projeto que mudariam para cada cliente, se forem poucos acredito que usar branch pode ser a solução mais rápida e simples. Porém o fork é a cópia de um projeto base que pode ser alterado livremente que no seu contexto parece ser mais interessante, ainda mais se no futuro você use o projeto base para novos clientes.

Comment: André é esse meu pensamento, ai teria 1 produto base com 2 variantes para cada cliente, qlq alteracao generica é feita na base e replicadas para os demais.

Sera que é a melhor forma para solucionar esse problema?

Comment: @RBoschini, acho que a melhor forma seria o projeto base ser projetado para aceitar parametrizações assim como funciona o Wordpress e outros CMS. Outra forma de fazer é desenvolver o projeto base de maneira genérica e as variantes teriam o projeto base como dependência.

Comment: Não iria adiantar, é um ecommerce e a maior variacao sera de layout e nao de regras de negocio.

a api continuara a mesma, apenas o front seguirá um base que ira se ramificar em 2 versoes levemente semelhantes.

Parametrizar isso nao seria o melhor caminho nesse caso.

Comment: Acabei resolvendo criando fork e fazendo sync com o projeto base qd preciso.

Answer (score 1):

Esse é o tipo de problema que um versionador de código não vai ajudar você a resolver, o que ele ajuda é na paralelização de um trabalho de desenvolvimento de software, mas o objetivo será sempre os ramos voltarem para o principal.

Eu recomendaria a você buscar uma solução na arquitetura, como fazer extensões ou plug-ins, existem frameworks para isso, em .Net existe o MEF, Managed Extensibility Framework e neste [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dd460648(v=vs.110).aspx) você pode saber como ele funciona e procurar para algo parecido para a plataforma que você usa.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar duas branches distintas no mesmo repositório. Assim vai ser mais prático manter as duas versões distintas quando precisar fazer alguma alteração que deseja aplicar em ambas as branches por meio de uma outra branch, `cherry-pick`, etc.

Contudo, **não recomendo** que faça isto com o seu projeto. Tente manter apenas uma **única versão da sua aplicação**. Se os clientes tem diferentes necessidades, controle isto com diferentes telas ou permissões. Se continuar com esta ideia, você terminará com duas aplicações distintas e o código que deseja aplicar em ambas não dará certo de tão diferente que as duas aplicações ficaram uma da outra. Isto virará um pesadelo para manter.

Comment: Eu sou testemunha desse inferno de manutenção. Tentou-se fazer isso de cada cliente ter seu branch específico. Na época, tínhamos uns 20 a 30 clientes nesse esquema; desses, 3 sobreviveram em 4 branches separados (sim, um cliente tem 2 branches) em que não há manutenção praticamente (e são infernais de manter, quando necessita), 2 voltaram para o ramo principal e o resto foi cancelado. Entre os motivos dos cancelamentos estava a instabilidade do software

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado, no começo sempre parece ser uma boa ideia. Inicialmente você evita o problema de gerenciar na mesma aplicação as features distintas, e tudo parece bom e as coisas fluem bem. Mas depois de um tempo o destino desta solução é sempre o caos, hehehe